# Where to find Microsoft Word 2013 when connected via RDP to a Windows Server 2012 Server

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, microsoft-office

I am running Windows Server 2012 on a virtual machine.
I am connecting to the virtual machine using the "Remote Desktop" connection.
For my work, I have installed

`Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 (English)`

When I go to Start - Control Panels - Programs and Features I can see that the Microsoft Office has been installed.

My question is:

How do I launch Microsoft Word on my Windows Server 2012?

I can't see any Microsoft Word icon on the desktop and I can't find anything about Microsoft Office or Microsoft word on the Windows Server 2012 start menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely in the "All Apps" drop down at the bottom of the Start Menu screen.  To bring it up, right click in the lower part of the screen on the start menu (not over an icon) and it should bring up the "All Apps" option... and should show you the complete program list..

Comment: +1 I'm so used to just typing and taking advantage of the instant search now that I forget about the "all apps" option

Comment: ditto...  But having used Windows 8, I end up using it as a last resort..

Comment: I spent a long time searching the Start Menu screen. Honestly, I did not notice the "All Apps" arrow in the bottom of the screen before I read your suggestion. In my humble opinion, having a text like "All apps" or "All programs" next to this little arrow would help me and other novice users who are coming to Windows Server 2012 from Windows7 or Windows XP..

Answer (score 0):

For me : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE"

Comment: This is the default location of the 32-bit version of Office. The 64 bit version would be slightly different location and it's also possible that the OP may not have installed it to the default location.

Answer (score 0):

With the importance of the Window Key in Server 2012 (And Windows 8.x) and the fact that RDP doesn't pass this key through by itself, you can use the Alt-Home key combination as a keyboard shortcut as a substitute for the Windows key in the RDP session. If you are really careful, you can also hover your mouse in one of the hot corners to bring up the appropriate Windows "charms" as well

Once you are on the start menu, you can start typing as it will automatically start the search function, find the appropriate office tile which you can then pin to the start page, taskbar, or to the desktop. You can also type "winword" for the search and find it that way.

Otherwise, you can browse out directly to your file system to the appropriate %ProgramFiles% or %ProgramFiles(x86)% Office install directory (depending on if you installed the 32-bit of 64-bit version of Office) - or to whatever directory you may have installed it to as part of a customized install.